# Textfields values are not appearing in Javascript when click on submit button ....using eembeddable widget in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, onclick, form-submit

Hello i'm new in nodejs i'm using nodejs widget now want to embed a signup form in it and the text values in javascript form should appear in the browser like in simple javascript it uses

```
 function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = document.getElementById('lname').value;
}

<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"  value="" placeholder="Enter your First Name" maxlength="110">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

`<p id="demo"></p>`

But it is not using in nodejs widget code

this is paltform.js where all javascript code is

```
/*eslint-disable no-extra-parens */
'use strict';
enter code here

console.log('hello from server');
(function(global) {
var serverHost = '<%= serverHost %>';
var partyId = '<%= partyId %>';
var useIframe = <%= useIframe %>;
init();
injectStyles();

function init() {
    var fooWidgets = document.querySelectorAll('.foo-widget');
    for (var i = 0; i < fooWidgets.length; ++i) {
        var fooWidget = fooWidgets[i];
        processFooWidget(fooWidget);
    }
}

function processFooWidget(fooWidget) {
    var id = fooWidget.getAttribute('data-foo-id');
    var processed = fooWidget.getAttribute('data-foo-processed');
    if (!id || processed === 'done') {
        //skip this one as it has either already been processed, or lacks an ID
        //This is done to ensure logic is not executed twice in the event that the
        //user erroneously embeds the script tag more than once on a single page
        console.log('skipping element:', fooWidget);
        return;
    }
        function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('f').innerHTML =  document.getElementById('fname').value;
}
    createFooWidget(fooWidget, id);
}


function createFooWidget(fooWidget, id) {
    <% if (useIframe) { %>
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/init?iframe=true&partyId='+partyId);
        iframe.setAttribute('class', 'foo-widget-iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('data-foo-id', id);
        iframe.setAttribute('width', '200px');
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
        iframe.style.border = 'none';
        iframe.style.height = '500px';
        iframe.style.width = '500px';
        iframe.style.position = 'relative';
        iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        fooWidget.appendChild(iframe);
        fooWidget.setAttribute('data-foo-processed', 'done');
    <% } else { %>
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            fooWidget.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            fooWidget.setAttribute('data-foo-processed', 'done');

            var fooWidgetButton = fooWidget.querySelector('.bar-button');
            if (!fooWidgetButton) {
                return;
            }


            var fooWidgetButtonFunction = function() {
                //TODO disable the button temporarily to prevent accidental double-click
                var barXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                barXhr.onload = function() {
                    var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    console.log(result);
                    var barPara = fooWidget.querySelector('.bar');
                    if (barPara) {
                        barPara.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
                    }
                };
                barXhr.open('POST', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/bar?partyId='+partyId);
                var content = {
                    fooId: id,
                };
                content = JSON.stringify(content);
                barXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
                barXhr.send(content);
            };
            if (fooWidgetButton.addEventListener) {
                fooWidgetButton.addEventListener('click', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
            }
            else if (fooWidgetButton.attachEvent) {
                fooWidgetButton.attachEvent('onclick', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
            }
            else {
                fooWidgetButton.onclick = fooWidgetButtonFunction;
            }
        };
        xhr.open("GET", serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/init?partyId='+partyId);
        xhr.send();
    <% } %>
}

//See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/inject-new-css-rules
function injectStyles() {
    var css = '<%= inlineCss %>';
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    }
    else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    var head = document.head || document.querySelector('head');
    head.appendChild(style);
}
}());
function injectStyle(rule) {
var div = $("<div />", {
html: '&shy;<style>' + rule + '</style>'
}).appendTo("body");
}
```

Following is the widget-init.html code

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"  value="" placeholder="Enter your First Name" maxlength="110">
<input class="btn-submit" id="btn-search" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Submit">

<p id="f"></p>

var serverHost = '<%= serverHost %>';
var id = '<%= id %>';
var partyId = '<%= partyId %>';
var fooWidget = document;
var fooWidgetButton = document.querySelector('.bar-button');
if (!fooWidgetButton) {
    return;
}
var fooWidgetButtonFunction = function() {
    //TODO disable the button temporarily to prevent accidental double-click
    var barXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    barXhr.onload = function() {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(result);
        var barPara = document.querySelector('.bar');
        if (barPara) {
            barPara.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    };
    barXhr.open('POST', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/bar?partyId='+partyId);
    var content = {
        fooId: id,
    };
    content = JSON.stringify(content);
    barXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    barXhr.send(content);
};
if (fooWidgetButton.addEventListener) {
    fooWidgetButton.addEventListener('click', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
}
else if (fooWidgetButton.attachEvent) {
    fooWidgetButton.attachEvent('onclick', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
}
else {
    fooWidgetButton.onclick = fooWidgetButtonFunction;
}


//myFunction Button Click

    var myFunctionButtonFunction = function() {
    //TODO disable the button temporarily to prevent accidental double-click
    var barXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    barXhr.onload = function() {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(result);
        var barPara = document.querySelector('.func');
        if (barPara) {
            barPara.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    };
    barXhr.open('POST', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/func?partyId='+partyId);
    var content = {
        fooId: id,
    };
    content = JSON.stringify(content);
    barXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    barXhr.send(content);
};
if (myFunctionButton.addEventListener) {
    myFunctionButton.addEventListener('click', myFunctionButtonFunction);
}
else if (myFunctionButton.attachEvent) {
    myFunctionButton.attachEvent('onclick', myFunctionButtonFunction);
}
else {
    myFunctionButton.onclick = myFunctionButtonFunction;
}
```

Comment: what is not working? Are you adding scripts in the head or the end of the body tag?

Comment: nope bro it's not regarding to front nd ........when click on submit button the values of the textfields should appear in browser and yes are appearing but i'm using nodejs .......in nodejs its not appearing.....in simple js yes values are appearing

Comment: provide nodejs code where you want to get that data

Comment: nodejs code is provided now

Comment: plz anybody guide me about this

Comment: @ArifKhan its showing  error in console nyFunction is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You need to write JavaScript code inside `<script>` tag in the file

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname"  value="" placeholder="Enter your First Name" maxlength="110">
<input class="btn-submit" id="btn-search" onclick="myFunction()" type="submit" value="Submit">

<p id="f"></p>
<script>

var serverHost = '<%= serverHost %>';
var id = '<%= id %>';
var partyId = '<%= partyId %>';
var fooWidget = document;
var fooWidgetButton = document.querySelector('.bar-button');
if (!fooWidgetButton) {
    return;
}
var fooWidgetButtonFunction = function() {
    //TODO disable the button temporarily to prevent accidental double-click
    var barXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    barXhr.onload = function() {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(result);
        var barPara = document.querySelector('.bar');
        if (barPara) {
            barPara.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    };
    barXhr.open('POST', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/bar?partyId='+partyId);
    var content = {
        fooId: id,
    };
    content = JSON.stringify(content);
    barXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    barXhr.send(content);
};
if (fooWidgetButton.addEventListener) {
    fooWidgetButton.addEventListener('click', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
}
else if (fooWidgetButton.attachEvent) {
    fooWidgetButton.attachEvent('onclick', fooWidgetButtonFunction);
}
else {
    fooWidgetButton.onclick = fooWidgetButtonFunction;
}


//myFunction Button Click

    var myFunctionButtonFunction = function() {
    //TODO disable the button temporarily to prevent accidental double-click
    var barXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    barXhr.onload = function() {
        var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(result);
        var barPara = document.querySelector('.func');
        if (barPara) {
            barPara.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    };
    barXhr.open('POST', serverHost+'/api/3rd/foo/widget/'+id+'/func?partyId='+partyId);
    var content = {
        fooId: id,
    };
    content = JSON.stringify(content);
    barXhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    barXhr.send(content);
};
if (myFunctionButton.addEventListener) {
    myFunctionButton.addEventListener('click', myFunctionButtonFunction);
}
else if (myFunctionButton.attachEvent) {
    myFunctionButton.attachEvent('onclick', myFunctionButtonFunction);
}
else {
    myFunctionButton.onclick = myFunctionButtonFunction;
}
</script>
```

Comment: of course bro i'm writing javascript code inside <script> here i upload code except <script> tag ........is not working

Comment: If you provide wrong code then How can we identify issue

Comment: all code that i'm providng you is right except some basic tags because i think stack overflow was not accepting code with those tags ....... idont know clear about stackoverflow i'm new here